# area calculation using lat/long in UIMapview

Tags: ios, mkmapview, area

I am trying to find area of MKPolygonView object added to MapView. Apple documentation has method distanceFromLocation: to find distance between edges of MKPolygonView object. But I could not find anything to calculate area of the overlay.

Does Apple have any documented method for finding area?

Comment: Triangulate the polygon and sum the area of each triangle?

Comment: @JamesWebster So there is no documented method? Earth surface is spherical so I don't think 2D calculations will be correct.

Comment: I don't know of a documented method. That is not to say that one doesn't exist. The Earth is spherical yes, but the maps you approximate the earth with aren't. It seems feasible that you could approximate area in 2D

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the comments on the question post, the Earth is not a perfect sphere either. In fact, it's not a perfect anything, so "correct" answers aren't possible. What matters is how accurate of an approximation you need.  Also, are you interested in a mean sea level type measurement, or do you want the actual contours of the ground (for example if your polygon is put over a mountain, then the same exact size polygon is put over some plains, should the result you calculate be the same or different)?

Depending on how big your polygon is, and which measurement you're looking for, a 2D approximation can be pretty accurate (the smaller the polygon, the closer you'll get).  Something to keep in mind, if you want your area in something like square feet, the distance between two longitudinal lines is not constant (63 deg west and 62 deg west are closer (in feet) somewhere in Alaska than they are at the equator).  You might have to do a unit conversion to handle this depending on how big your polygon is (or if your polygon could be placed anywhere).  If you can't do the 2D approximation, I'm not even sure how you'd do that.

When I did this, I did the 2D approx, and I had to do the unit conversion.  If that's the way you go, I can try to dig up some of my old notes and the links I used to get you started.